# How should i modify this code to allow me to let turtles turn randomly down paths at a junction?

Tags: netlogo

I have created a new patch type which allows turtles to turn randomly down various paths while one a junction patch ( with pcolor 6 ). How should I modify this code so that I do not get the error "Towards expected input to be an agent but got nobody instead." The code is as follows :

```
if pcolor = 6 [ set heading towards  one-of neighbors in-cone 1 180]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If your turtle is in a corner and you turned off wrapping, there may not be any such neighbors.  You have to decide what to do in this circumstance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specifically answer your question, you need to check if there are any patches that fulfill your criteria. To do that, you can do

```
ask a-turtle [if any? neighbors in-cone 1 180 [face one-of neighbors in-cone 1 180]]
```

Doing it this way, you will create the same turtle set twice (when you check if there are any, and before you face one of them), so a more optimized way of doing this is:

```
ask a-turtle [
  let eligible-neighbors neighbors in-cone 1 180
  if any? eligible-neighbors [face one-of eligible-neighbors]
]
```

That said, I think Alan is right that you are getting this error because you have wrapping off and your turtles are either in a corner or facing a wall. If this is the case, you need to figure out what to do in that case. If you just want them to turn around and keep going, you could use `ifelse` like this:

```
ask a-turtle [
  let eligible-neighbors neighbors in-cone 1 180
  ifelse any? eligible-neighbors 
    [face one-of eligible-neighbors] ;; face a neighboring patch if there are any
    [rt 180] ;; else, turn around 180 degrees
]
```

Answer (score 0):

try first making a temporary variable with 'let', then setting the heading towards that.

e.g.

```
let FaceHere one-of neighbors in-cone 1 180
face FaceHere
```

haven't tried that - just an idea.

by the way, you can replace

```
set heading towards
```

with

```
 face
```

Comment: This cannot be used to set a heading towards a patch in a certain cone of vision of the turtles can it?